# Reverse Engineering Linux Core Dump

Tags: ida, linux, gdb

I have a Linux Core Dump file for a binary (which apparently crashed during execution)

`file` command on the core dump:

```
core.123: ELF 64-bit LSB  core file x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), SVR4-style, from '/home/user/a.out'
```

I have the binary, `a.out`, as well.

How can I analyse the crash in more details with this information?

I loaded the core using GDB using the command:

```
gdb -c core
```

I can look at the backtrace of the stack using the `bt` command. And I can see that the program crashed due to: `SIGTRAP`

```
Core was generated by `/home/user/a.out'.
Program terminated with signal SIGTRAP, Trace/breakpoint trap.
#0  0x0000000000400566 in ?? ()
(gdb) bt
#0  0x0000000000400566 in ?? ()
#1  0x00007ffff7a3b1bb in ?? ()
#2  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
(gdb) x/i 0x0000000000400566
=> 0x400566:    retq
```

However, I'd like to get more detailed information about the root cause of the crash.

Does IDA Pro support analysis of core dump files? If I have the original binary, can I do something to debug it in details?

I would prefer IDA Pro with remote debugging support in this case. However, if there's a way to do using GDB efficiently here, that's okay as well.

Comment: Do you have the source code?

Comment: @user202729: of a *core dump*!? Of the code that led to the core dump? Of the code that writes out a core dump?

Comment: @usr2564301 I mean, that compiles to the a.out file.